Deploying Embedded Power BI Reports for Client-Specific Access: Free Publishing and User Login Setup
How do I share a Power BI report with certain clients using embedded code for free? And could you explain, in simple steps, how to set up secure login credentials for those clients to access the report without risking data loss?
So, I've created a report and set up an embedded version in workspace. The issue is, when I embed it, anyone can access it. When I try embedding it for specific users, it requires logins, but those logins only work for people within the company. Another option I've explored is adding it through Azure directory, but sometimes there are security settings, like cross-tenant security settings, that stop from doing that. These settings are put in place by clients to prevent data breaches. Sometimes it works, but then there's a 60-day free trial, which may not be ideal for long-term use.
To try all that I have premium license in my company.

Since, you have mentioned that you have explored on adding the specific clients through Azure Directory. Can you please confirm whether you have added the specific client to the 'Users' and then given access to the specific client to the workspace where your report is present?
Here are some snapshots for your reference:

Azure Portal - Adding the client as the 'User'


Giving access to the client as admin to the workspace.



Also, please make sure that your azure application being used for embedding is configured as a Multitenant application.
This is one of the ways of giving access to specific clients. However, if any client has cross-tenant security settings applied, then you may need to work with them to ensure that necessary permissions are granted to view the embedded report after login.
